# d3 rotating text labels

Tags: d3.js, axis-labels

I have text labels that I would like to rotate.

```
  in_years.selectAll(".xlabel")     
      .data(xTickLabels)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class","xlabel")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end") 
      //.attr("transform", "translate(0,0) rotate(-45)")
      .attr("font-size", "14px")
      .attr("x", (d,i) => xScale(xRange[i]))
      .attr("y", (d,i) => height+15)
      .text(function(d) { console.log(d);return d})
      ;
```

Wit "transform" line commented I obtain graph 1. Uncommenting the line I obtain graph 2 which does not make sense to me.

Any hint on why this happen and how to solve it? I am using d3 v3 for this [image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why the rotation effect not as your expectation is due to the css property of rotate().** [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate)

According to the rotate function definition in MDN doc:
''**The axis of rotation passes through an origin**''

So you have to translate each text element's (x,y) in order to let rotation axis is related to its site in the graphic.

```
// this code, which each text will rotate according to (0,0)
svg.selectAll('text.norotation')
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append('text')
   .text((d)=>d)
   .classed('norotation', true)
   .attr('fill', 'black')
   .attr('x', (d,i)=> xScale(i))
   .attr('y', 200)
```

Modified One

```
//each text element will rotate according to its position
svg.selectAll('text.rotation')
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append('text')
   .text((d)=>d)
   .classed('rotation', true)
   .attr('fill', 'black')
   .attr('transform', (d,i)=>{
        return 'translate( '+xScale(i)+' , '+220+'),'+ 'rotate(45)';})
   .attr('x', 0)
   .attr('y', 0)
```

Demo on Observalbe:https://beta.observablehq.com/@weitinglin/d3-rotating-text-labels

Comment: Thank you Weiting Lin for your crystal clear and detail answer which indeed solved my problem. Thank you and have a nice day!